# Checking equality with a HashSet of objects

Tags: c#, hashset, iequalitycomparer

I am trying to compare two hashsets of `Definition` type as `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, oldValue)`. `Definition` is defined as follows

```
public class Definition
{
    public string Variable { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Location> LocationList { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Definition other = obj as Definition;
        return other.Variable.Equals(this.Variable) && other.LocationList!= null &&this.LocationList != null
            && other.LocationList.Count == this.LocationList.Count
            && other.LocationList == this.LocationList;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Variable.GetHashCode() ^ this.LocationList.Count.GetHashCode();// ^ this.LocationList.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Line { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string CodeTab { get; set; }
    public Location(int line, int col, int pos, string tab)
    {
        Line = line;
        Column = col;
        Position = pos;
        CodeTab = tab;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Location other = obj as Location;
        return this.CodeTab == other.CodeTab
            && this.Position == other.Position
            && this.Column == other.Column
            && this.Line == other.Line;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.CodeTab.GetHashCode() ^ this.Position.GetHashCode() 
            ^ this.Column.GetHashCode() ^ this.Line.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Somehow for a similar set, the result is returned as `false` despite all the information remaining the same. The only difference is that the position of some elements are interchanged, but I know that `HashSet` won't preserve or check the order while comparing. Can any one advise me on what is going wrong here?

PS: I tried uncommenting `this.LocationList.GetHashCode()` also, but didn't work.

Comment: That's a `HashSet<Location>` not a `HashSet<Definition>` but you state that you want to compare _"two hashsets of Definition"_. So either your question is asking the wrong or your code does something different.

Comment: `value` and `oldValue` are `Definition` types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a comparer for the sets:

```
var setComparer = HashSet<Location>.CreateSetComparer();
return other.Variable.Equals(this.Variable) && setComparer.Equals(this.LocationList, other.LocationList);
```

Answer (score 0):

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will look for an object implementing `IEquatable<T>`. Otherwise, it will defer to an `ObjectEqualityComparer`, which simply checks for reference equality. This is why you're seeing false when references are compared.

What you actually want to do is explicitly implement `IEquatable<Location>`. Note you should really make your properties immutable for this to work properly:

```
public class Location : IEquatable<Location>
{       
    public Location(int line, int col, int pos, string tab)
    {
        Line = line;
        Column = col;
        Position = pos;
        CodeTab = tab;
    }

    public int Line { get; private set; }
    public int Column { get; private set; }
    public int Position { get; private set; }
    public string CodeTab { get; private set; }

    public bool Equals(Location other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(CodeTab, other.CodeTab) && Column == other.Column && Line == other.Line && Position == other.Position;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Location) obj);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Location left, Location right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Location left, Location right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (CodeTab != null ? CodeTab.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Column;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Line;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Position;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you look at the type `EqualityComparer` created by `Default`, you'll see `GenericEqualityComparer<Location>`:

```
Console.WriteLine(EqualityComparer<Location>.Default.GetType())
```